# what is the purpose of "npm install package-name --no-save"?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I mean why would anyone install a package temporarily and not add it to the dependencies list ?

`--no-save` uses?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you just want to test an idea without the need to add a package in the `dependency` or `devDependencies` of your `package.json` file.

if you run:

```sh
npm install --no-save express
```

now, if you check your `node_modules` folder the package is downloaded but `package.json` is not updated.

When you try to run your code, since `express` is available in `node_module` it can be picked up by your code or any third party library that you have in your project.

Comment: It may also be useful for CI. Since you don't want it to update the package.json during the npm install process.